# How do I make a word upper case using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have the following string:

```
var str = "string";
```

I'd like for it to match this expression:

```
/(^[a-z])/
```

So that it can be replaced by this expression:

```
/([A-Z])/
```

This means that it will make the first lower case letter upper case.

Here is what I've tried:

```
"string".replace(/(^[a-z])/, /([A-Z])/);
```

The problem is that `/([A-Z])/` catches the first character and replaces it with the following raw text `/([A-Z])/`.

Comment: Isn't this misunderstanding of how regex works? You can't use regex in replacement (except `\1`, `\n`, etc.).

Comment: note that replace can take a lambda as second argument : 'string'.replace(/([a-z]+)/,x=>x.toUpperCase()), however 'string'.toUpperCase() is shorter. another solution : 'string'.replace(/[a-z]/g,x=>String.fromCodePoint(x.codePointAt(0)-32))

Comment: previous command fails because SO inserts weird characters in comments

Comment: please remove all blockquotes from your questions and answers. This is a matter that has been discussed on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a regex as the second parameter of the method [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), but this parameters expects `newSubstr|function`.

You could use the replace method and pass a function as the second parameter:

```js
var str = "string";
str = str.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(match) {
  return match.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(str);
```

If you want to capitalize the first letter of the word "string" using Javascript, you could also do this without using a regex:

- Get the first character of the string using [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)
- Convert the first character to upper case using [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)
- Then for example use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) with an offset of 1 to get the rest of the characters in the string

```js
var str = "string";
str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
console.log(str);
```